# JW Player / Flowplayer playing RTMP stream from FMS 3.5

Tags: video-streaming, jwplayer, rtmp, flowplayer, flash-media-server

I'm a bit out of my depth, but I've been asked to help update the player on a NFP website (I normally do server-side C#) that uses Flash Media Player 3.5, and has RTMP running streams, currently using ZoomPlayer. They want to update to something better, preferably Flowplayer, but I've also been looking at JW player.

They have existing XML playlist files (e.g. http://www.marewatchers.com/playlist/caidnjax_playlist.xml)

Is it possible to use these files in either of the players?

If not, could someone please help me get the URLs correct. As an example, from the playlist above there is streamer rtmp://50.30.42.129:80/live/caidnjax and streamname caidnjax, but I've not manager to get this to work in either of these players, though have tested in third-party tests that take the input as separate parameters.

Thanks in advance

Mark

Answer (score 0):

JW Player does support RTMP streaming. You will need to set primary: "flash" in this setup config, since JW7's default is HTML5.

Here is some documentation on the embed process that should help: https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1430358

If you need more assistance, could you post your test code? I got a permissions error when I tried to test with your playlist.